# Adding xml node on top of file or reverse the loop

Tags: php, xml, foreach, nodes

I am using xml. Reading the xml-document works fine, adding nodes works fine to but I want the node to add on top of the xml file. Is this possible or is this a nogo?

The reason I want this is because when I display the xml file I want the last added node, displayed as the newest one, on top.

I display the xml with this loop:

```
foreach($xml->xpath("//user[@id='12345678']") as $user){
        foreach($user->children() as $action => $data){
          echo"<li>";   
          echo $data->content;
          echo $data->date;
           echo"</li>"; 
        }
   }
```

If there is a way to reverse the loop or another way I'm fine with that to, it doesn't have to be adding the first node on top. Below are the file how I add the node and the structure of the xml-file.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

addxml.php

```
<?php
$file = "actielijst.xml";
$fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");
$str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");

// get document element
echo "<xmp>OLD:\n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$root   = $xml->documentElement;

$content     = $xml->createElement("content");
$contentText = $xml->createTextNode("Nieuwe Factuur Mei");
$content->appendChild($contentText);

$date     = $xml->createElement("date");
$dateText = $xml->createTextNode("23-12-2010");
$date->appendChild($dateText);

$action   = $xml->createElement("action");
$action->appendChild($date);
$action->appendChild($content);

$root->appendChild($action);

$xml->save("actielijst.xml") or die("Error");

?>
```

actielijst.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <userid>
      ------->  Insert new action here <------
      <action>
         <date>23-01-2010</date>
         <content>nieuwe factuur</content>
      </action>
      <action>
         <date>23-01-2010</date>
         <content>karten op 01-02</content>
      </action>
    </userid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to capture every parent node (action in your case) and then reverse the array...

```
$users_arr = array_reverse($xml->xpath("action"));
```

Now you can loop through this array!

Comment: And then like this: foreach($users_arr as $user){ ? Because that way it does not work..

Comment: sorry based on your XML, the xpath value needs to be action, not userid... Have edited the above code accordingly

Comment: It now loops through the array and shows 4 li components, like the for rules in the xml but the echo $data is empty.

Comment: Okay the echo $data->date; and $data->content; are empty. If I only echo $data it displays everything next to each other like:         date content date content and if I echo a break, it breaks all four elements. How do I get it like date content <br /> date content <br />?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 23-01-2010 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => karten op 01-02 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 23-01-2010 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => nieuwe factuur )

Comment: Stupid. It isn't absolutly neccesary for me to put date and content in different tags, so now I put them together and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help :)!

Answer (score 0):

This will helps

```
<?php

$file = "actielijst.xml";

$fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");

$str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($str);

$action = $xml->addChild('action');

$action->addChild('content','sundar');

$action->addChild('date','23-12-2010');

header('content-type: application/xml');

echo $xml->saveXML();
```